# Read a GDB table into a pandas dataframe in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, pandas

I have a set of tables that I have exported to a file geodatabase. I would like to read it into python as a pandas dataframe. When I try to read the file directly using `pd.read_csv`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'path\to\your\gdb.gdb\file')
```

I get the error:

```
IOError: File path\to\your\gdb.gdb\file does not exist
```

How can I read the table into a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use da.SearchCursor:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
table = r"C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb\grids"
columns = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table) if f.type!="Geometry"] #List the fields you want to include. I want all columns except the geometry
df = pd.DataFrame(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, columns), columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS has a function that converts [Table to a NumPy Array](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/tabletonumpyarray.htm) and [FeatureClass To NumPy Array](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/featureclasstonumpyarray.htm), so you need to convert to a NumPy Array and then convert to a Pandas Dataframe

There's a code example,

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

def arcgis_table_to_df(in_fc, input_fields=None, query=""):
    """Function will convert an arcgis table into a pandas dataframe with an object ID index, and the selected
    input fields using an arcpy.da.SearchCursor.
    :param - in_fc - input feature class or table to convert
    :param - input_fields - fields to input to a da search cursor for retrieval
    :param - query - sql query to grab appropriate values
    :returns - pandas.DataFrame"""
    OIDFieldName = arcpy.Describe(in_fc).OIDFieldName
    if input_fields:
        final_fields = [OIDFieldName] + input_fields
    else:
        final_fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(in_fc)]
    data = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_fc,final_fields,where_clause=query)]
    fc_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=final_fields)
    fc_dataframe = fc_dataframe.set_index(OIDFieldName,drop=True)
    return fc_dataframe

def arcgis_table_to_dataframe(in_fc, input_fields, query="", skip_nulls=False, null_values=None):
    """Function will convert an arcgis table into a pandas dataframe with an object ID index, and the selected
    input fields. Uses TableToNumPyArray to get initial data.
    :param - in_fc - input feature class or table to convert
    :param - input_fields - fields to input into a da numpy converter function
    :param - query - sql like query to filter out records returned
    :param - skip_nulls - skip rows with null values
    :param - null_values - values to replace null values with.
    :returns - pandas dataframe"""
    OIDFieldName = arcpy.Describe(in_fc).OIDFieldName
    if input_fields:
        final_fields = [OIDFieldName] + input_fields
    else:
        final_fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(in_fc)]
    np_array = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(in_fc, final_fields, query, skip_nulls, null_values)
    object_id_index = np_array[OIDFieldName]
    fc_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np_array, index=object_id_index, columns=input_fields)
    return fc_dataframe
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/d-wasserman/e9c98be1d0caebc2935afecf0ba239a0)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the GeoAccessor from arcgis...

```
import pandas as pd
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor
df = pd.DataFrame(GeoAccessor.from_table(r'Path to table'))
```

Assuming you would also like to export the table back to a file geodatabase you can use

```
import pandas as pd
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor
df = pd.DataFrame(GeoAccessor.from_table(r'Path to table'))
df.spatial.to_table(r'Path\tablename')
```